# JavaMail IMAP Connection Refused - Telnet works

Tags: java, networking, content-management-system, jakarta-mail, imap

I'm trying to use JavaMail in order to connect to an IMAP Server (on a remote virtual linux machine - Ubuntu 14 LTS) but I'm getting the following exception:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

I've already tried to establish the connection via Telnet and everything works.

The JavaMail version I'm using is 1.5.5 (also tested with 1.4.7) and I'm using the following properties:

```
    Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    properties.setProperty("mail.imap.host", SERVER);
    properties.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imap");
    properties.put("mail.imap.port", PORT);

    Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, null);
    Store store = session.getStore("imap");
    store.connect(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
```

***Notes:***

- *It's working on my personal machine*
- *It's working on another external machine*
- *It's failing on the remote linux virtual machine*
- *The IMAP server is on a different machine - which is accessible to all of the previous*

I've done some research and some people told that it could be a firewall/blocking issue but how am I able to connect via Telnet?

Thanks.

**Edited**

The telnet command I've applied in the test-run:

```
telnet <server_ip> <port>
```

After this, the connection is successfuly established and I'm able to apply IMAP commands such as *list status*.

The output from javamail when it fails is the following:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:233)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:189)
    at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:107)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.<init>(IMAPProtocol.java:104)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:538)
    ... 12 more
```

Comment: try `telnet <your SERVER ip> <your PORT>`
if it does not connect you need to modify your iptables

Comment: hello, like I said on the post, when using telnet it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution!!

I performed a network capture on the remote machine and I saw that for some reason the javamail api was using the default IMAP folder and not the one I've selected..

Further tests revealed that changing the property value type to String instead of Integer solved this issue. It's important to notice that this didn't happen on other environments so I'm not sure the reason I had to make this change.

Answer (score 0):

Firewalls usually work port based. This means telnet (23/TCP) can be allowed whereas IMAP (usually 143/993) is blocked.

You should check the firewall and check if the IMAP port is open.

Comment: I'm not sure I get it.. when I use 'telnet <your SERVER ip> <your PORT>', am I not specifying the port I'm gonna use? Currently I'm using telnet with the IMAP port (not 23).

Answer (score 0):

Where is your program running?  If you [change getDefaultInstance to getInstance](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#getdefaultinstance) does it work?

Comment: Update your post with the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) and the telnet command and output.  Use copy/paste so you don't copy it wrong.  You're running telnet on the same machine that you're running your JavaMail application on, right?

Comment: Yes, I've executed telnet on the same machine. @post updated.

Comment: Exactly what server did you connect to and exactly what port did you connect to?  Also, please post the JavaMail debug output.